# Нажатие на кнопку в ToolBar (SendMessage) в стороннем приложении

Tags: c#, winapi, toolbar, sendmessage

Имеется диалоговое окно, handle которого я поймал, так же обнаружил handle принадлежащий ToolbarWindow32, никак не получается нажать на одну из 4 кнопок в тулбаре.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr ptr = WinAPI.FindWindow(null, "Выберите файл");
    IntPtr hWndtoolBar = FindWindowByIndex(ptr, 1, "ToolbarWindow32");
    // тут пытаюсь достучаться до toolbar 
    var but = WinAPI.SendMessage(hWndtoolBar, (int)WinAPI.GetWindow_Cmd.TB_BUTTONCOUNT, 0, 0); // сообщение принято but = 4
    TBBUTTON Button = new TBBUTTON();
    WinAPI.SendMessage(hWndtoolBar, (int)WinAPI.GetWindow_Cmd.TB_GETBUTTON, 1, Button); // так пытался заполнить структуру        
    WinAPI.SendMessage(hWndtoolBar, (int)(WinAPI.GetWindow_Cmd.WM_USER + 3), 2, 0); // так пытался нажать на кнопку
}

public struct TBBUTTON
    {
        public long iBitmap;
        public long idCommand;
        public byte fsState;
        public byte fsStyle;
        public long dwData;
        public long iString;
    }
```

Увы, кнопки нажиматься отказываются. Нашел немного материала по VBA, но не могу перенести код на C#. Удалось перенести только часть. 
Информацию нашел здесь: [1 источник](http://www.vbnet.ru/forum/show.aspx?id=179384), [2 источник](http://www.delphimaster.net/view/4-1098254440)

К сожалению никак не могу сориентироваться, как мне добиться нажатия кнопки именно с помощью кода на C#. 
Если кто-нибудь может подсказать, буду благодарен!
**UDP:**

Попробовал кликнуть по кнопке таким образом:

```
public static void MouseClick(IntPtr hWnd, MouseButton btn, int x, int y)
    {
        int xyPoint = NativeMacros.MAKELONG(x, y);
        int wParam = GetWParamFromButton(btn);

        SendMessage(hWnd, (int) btn, wParam, xyPoint);
        SendMessage(hWnd, (int) btn + 1, wParam, xyPoint);
    }

private static int GetWParamFromButton(MouseButton btn)
    {
        switch (btn)
        {
            case MouseButton.Left:
                return 0x0001;
            case MouseButton.Middle:
                return 0x0010;
            case MouseButton.Right:
                return 0x0002;
            default:
                throw new Win32Exception("Невозможно преобразовать значение!");
        }
    }

public static int MAKELONG(int x, int y)
    {
        return (x & 0xffff) | ((y & 0xffff) << 16);
    }

WinAPI.MouseClick((IntPtr)ptr, MouseButton.Left, 47, 441);// добавил в код
```

Я конечно могу косячить с координатами ибо добавил изображение в paint и посмотрел номера пикселей, но не на столько же.. пробовал и обычные кнопки таким образом нажать, ничего не вышло. Кнопку не из тулбара удалось нажать только поймав handle самой кнопки. Тулбаровские все никак не поддаются.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду отследить координаты кнопок и слать клик мышью по этим координатам? 
На самом деле думал об этом варианте, но не пробовал надеясь сделать через TB_PRESSBUTTON. Вопрос пока не закрыт, но реализовать все же хочется первым способом...
UPD: посмотрел, обнаружил что слал клик мышью, но в тулбар, однако ни ответа ни привета...

Comment: ладно буду пробовать

Comment: Дополнил информацию о попытках, возможно не правильно использовал Ваш совет. Если это так, пожалуйста подскажите куда копнуть..

Comment: Почему сразу кучи кода, я вызвал, указал координаты, в итоге если указывать handle окна, то ни по каким координатам кнопки я не попадаю, а даже если попадаю то она не срабатывает, иная ситуация с handle самой кнопки, тут все работает нормально, но это не решает проблему.
Информативной была последняя строка, она не сработала.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гораздо проще делать то же самое с помощью [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ee684009(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
using System.Windows.Automation;
//....
var runWindow = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hWndtoolBar);
var list = runWindow.FindAll(TreeScope.Subtree, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button));

if (list.Count > 1)
{
    var button = list[1]; // выбираем вторую кнопку
    if (button.Current.IsEnabled)
    {
        var invokePattern = button.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
        invokePattern.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Не забудьте подключить к проекту Reference: UIAutomationClient, UIAutomationTypes.

---

Если же использовать ваш подход, нужно сначала получить координаты кнопки внутри окна тулбара. Для этого существует сообщение [TB_GETITEMRECT](http://TB_GETITEMRECT).
Оно требует на вход указатель. Но вы не можете просто так передать обычный указатель, т.к. находитесь в адресном пространстве другого процесса.
Вам необходимо выделить память в адресном пространстве целевого процесса.

Потом отправить WM_LBUTTONDOWN и WM_LBUTTONUP (эмулировать нажатие). Можно еще попробовать TB_PRESSBUTTON, но оно работает начиная с Vista.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr handle, out int processId);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(
         ProcessAccessFlags processAccess,
         bool bInheritHandle,
         int processId
    );
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern Int32 ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] buffer, UInt32 size, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress,
       uint dwSize, AllocationType flAllocationType, MemoryProtection flProtect);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool VirtualFreeEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint dwFreeType);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
    public enum VirtualFreeExTypes : uint {
        MEM_DECOMMIT = 0x4000,
        MEM_RELEASE = 0x8000
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum AllocationType {
        Commit = 0x1000,
        Reserve = 0x2000,
        Decommit = 0x4000,
        Release = 0x8000,
        Reset = 0x80000,
        Physical = 0x400000,
        TopDown = 0x100000,
        WriteWatch = 0x200000,
        LargePages = 0x20000000
    }
    [Flags]
    public enum MemoryProtection {
        Execute = 0x10,
        ExecuteRead = 0x20,
        ExecuteReadWrite = 0x40,
        ExecuteWriteCopy = 0x80,
        NoAccess = 0x01,
        ReadOnly = 0x02,
        ReadWrite = 0x04,
        WriteCopy = 0x08,
        GuardModifierflag = 0x100,
        NoCacheModifierflag = 0x200,
        WriteCombineModifierflag = 0x400
    }
    [Flags]
    public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint {
        All = 0x001F0FFF,
        Terminate = 0x00000001,
        CreateThread = 0x00000002,
        VirtualMemoryOperation = 0x00000008,
        VirtualMemoryRead = 0x00000010,
        VirtualMemoryWrite = 0x00000020,
        DuplicateHandle = 0x00000040,
        CreateProcess = 0x000000080,
        SetQuota = 0x00000100,
        SetInformation = 0x00000200,
        QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
        QueryLimitedInformation = 0x00001000,
        Synchronize = 0x00100000
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT {
        public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
    }
    const int WM_USER = 0x0400;
    const int TB_GETITEMRECT = (WM_USER + 29);
    const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
    public static int MAKELONG(int x, int y)
    {
        return (x & 0xffff) | ((y & 0xffff) << 16);
    }
    public static RECT ByteArrayToRect(byte[] bytes)
    {
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        RECT stuff = (RECT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
            handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(RECT));
        handle.Free();
        return stuff;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = WinAPI.FindWindow(null, "Выберите файл");
        IntPtr window = FindWindowByIndex(ptr, 1, "ToolbarWindow32");
        IntPtr nNumberOfBytesRead;
        int dwProcessID;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, out dwProcessID);
        IntPtr hProcess = OpenProcess((ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryOperation | ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryRead | ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryWrite), false, dwProcessID);
        IntPtr Pointer = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, (IntPtr)0, 4096, AllocationType.Reserve | AllocationType.Commit, MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);

        RECT bi;
        SendMessage(window, TB_GETITEMRECT, (IntPtr)1 /* индекс кнопки*/, (IntPtr)Pointer);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16];
        ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (Pointer), buffer, (uint)buffer.Length, out nNumberOfBytesRead);
        bi = ByteArrayToRect(buffer);
        PostMessage(window, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)MAKELONG(bi.Left, bi.Top));
        PostMessage(window, WM_LBUTTONUP, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)MAKELONG(bi.Left, bi.Top));
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, Pointer, 0, (uint)VirtualFreeExTypes.MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }
```

Comment: Ого, ничего себе!

Comment: @VladD что именно вызвало ваше удивление?

Comment: Ну, например, работа с памятью другого процесса :) Теперь и на C#! (Первую часть ответа я как бы ожидал, но не вторую.)

Comment: @VladD самое сложное было перевести 10 строчек c С++ на C#, где каждую структуру и функцию Winapi надо декларировать. Правда, не хватает проверки ошибок, но думаю автор справится.
https://gist.github.com/zenden2k/3d577f72627fe2430940

Comment: @zenden2k Большое спасибо за информацию, жаль что ответ получил только вчера. На самом деле находил ответы связанные с UI Automation и объяснения, и код взаимодействия с другим процессом, но не мог перевести его в C#.
Задачу решил путем посылки сообщений с нажатием клавиш "Tab", "Space", "Return", "Up", "Down", найденным handle от ToolBar и SystemListView. В скором времени размещу, как один из вариантов решения.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, решение оказалось проще чем реализация обращений к другому процессу и само собой потратило меньше времени чем переписывание имеющегося кода в формате UI Automation. Решение как я уже писал, заключается в следующем: посылка сообщений с нажатием функциональных клавиш.

```
IntPtr ptr = WinAPI.FindWindow(null, "Выберите файл");
IntPtr hWndtoolBar = FindWindowByIndex(ptr, 1, "ToolbarWindow32");
// потребовалось установить фокус в тулбар (также и с любым другим элементом)
WinAPI.SendMessage(hWndtoolBar, (int)(WinAPI.GetWindow_Cmd.WM_SETFOCUS), 0, 0);
Thread.Sleep(2500); //приходится приостанавливать главный поток, ибо пока не произойдут
//изменения в UI, бесполезно посылать какие либо сообщения.

// вот такая обертка для SysListView32 попалась мне
IntPtr hWndSHELLDLL = FindWindowByIndex(ptr, 1, "SHELLDLL_DefView");
IntPtr hWndListView = FindWindowByIndex(hWndSHELLDLL, 1, "SysListView32");
Thread.Sleep(2500);
WinAPI.SendMessage(hWndListView, (int)(WinAPI.GetWindow_Cmd.WM_SETFOCUS), 0, 0); 
WinAPI.SendMessage(hWndListView, (int)(WinAPI.GetWindow_Cmd.WM_KEYDOWN), 40, 0);
```

дальше все в том же духе. 

Команды:

```
public enum GetWindow_Cmd : uint
    {           
        WM_KEYDOWN = 256,
        WM_KEYUP = 257,
        WM_SETFOCUS = 7
    }
```

Надеюсь и это кому-нибудь пригодится)

P.S. Для просмотра компонентов использовал Window Detective, мне он показался удобнее чем Spy++.